# Create a font file using svg's

Tags: c#, fonts, icons

I'm trying to create a C# application which takes a selection of SVG's, and turns them into an Icon font. So first things first I need to create a font made out of the selected SVG's.

The only thing I can find is on how to create new font families e.g.

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
```

Not actually generating a new font file. Is it possible to create a `.tff`, just like you can create a `.txt` file?

Comment: Asking for "*Any useful links*" immediately consigns this question to closure: we [*don't do shopping*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/); if you can rephrase the question to ask about how to use [tag:c#] to convert [tag:svg]s into icon-fonts that would, likely, be an interesting question. Though your tags ([tag:html] and [tag:css]) seem irrelevant to the question itself.

Comment: My only problem with asking 'how to use c# to convert svg's into icon-fonts' is that people want to know what I have already tried. I haven't tried anything yet as I don't know where to start with this topic. I just wanted some background info :/ @DavidThomas

Comment: @Ralt Did You found anything? I'm planning to create custom tool to build font icons, but as You I can't find anything on how to get started. There are libraries like svg2ttf (https://github.com/fontello/svg2ttf) and pages like font2web, but I'm searching for C# solution.

Comment: @Misiu Nope, I haven't been able to find anything yet.